# Using .dll with European digit system, but my System uses American digit system

Tags: c#, internationalization, number-formatting, decimal-point

I'm remaking my previous exam for exercise, we got an European .dll file with a simple method that returns a string eg. *10,20;34,5;12,3;* . The problem is in Europe instead of . for point values, we use a comma. So when I try to parse this it doesn't give me correct values or doesn't want to parse at all.

```
// method.call() is just an example for calling the .dll method that returns the European format
double number;
if(!double.TryParse(method.call(), out number)) throw new ArgumentException("this is not a double");
```

I tried to show the output instead in Console.WritLine() and it showed me the digit with commas. So I guess this is the problem. Because when I enter digits with points it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Double__) overload. By passing the CultureInfo used for parsing, you can switch to a European culture.

```
var value = "12,3";
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de"); // german culture info
if (Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, culture, out var number))
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);

value = "12.3";
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); // american culture info
if (Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, culture, out number))
  Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
```